# How to Implement tooltip in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**I have implemented a double Y-axis area chart. can anyone tell me how to implement tooltip or do it?**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style> /* set the CSS */
    
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    .axisSteelBlue text{
      fill: steelblue;
    }
    
    .axisRed text{
      fill: red;
    }
    div.tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      width: 60px;
      height: 28px;
      padding: 2px;
      font: 12px sans-serif;
      background: lightsteelblue;
      border: 0px;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
     
    <!-- load the d3.js library -->     
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    // parse the date / time
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");
    
    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y0 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
    var y1 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
    
    // define the 1st line
    var valueline = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y0(d.close); });
    
    // define the 2nd line
    var valueline2 = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y1(d.open); });
    
    // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        
    
    // Get the data
    var data = [
      {
        "date": "1-May-12",
        "close": 58.13,
        "open": 3.41
      },
      {
        "date": "30-Apr-12",
        "close": 53.98,
        "open": 4.55
      },
      {
        "date": "27-Apr-12",
        "close": 67,
        "open": 6.78
      },
      {
        "date": "26-Apr-12",
        "close": 89.7,
        "open": 7.85
      },
      {
        "date": "25-Apr-12",
        "close": 99,
        "open": 8.92
      },
      {
        "date": "24-Apr-12",
        "close": 130.28,
        "open": 9.92
      },
      {
        "date": "23-Apr-12",
        "close": 166.7,
        "open": 10.13
      },
      {
        "date": "20-Apr-12",
        "close": 234.98,
        "open": 12.23
      },
      {
        "date": "19-Apr-12",
        "close": 345.44,
        "open": 13.45
      },
      {
        "date": "18-Apr-12",
        "close": 443.34,
        "open": 16.04
      },
      {
        "date": "17-Apr-12",
        "close": 543.7,
        "open": 18.03
      },
      {
        "date": "16-Apr-12",
        "close": 580.13,
        "open": 21.02
      },
      {
        "date": "13-Apr-12",
        "close": 605.23,
        "open": 22.34
      },
      {
        "date": "12-Apr-12",
        "close": 622.77,
        "open": 20.15
      },
      {
        "date": "11-Apr-12",
        "close": 626.2,
        "open": 21.26
      },
      {
        "date": "10-Apr-12",
        "close": 628.44,
        "open": 31.04
      },
      {
        "date": "9-Apr-12",
        "close": 636.23,
        "open": 35.04
      },
      {
        "date": "5-Apr-12",
        "close": 633.68,
        "open": 41.02
      },
      {
        "date": "4-Apr-12",
        "close": 624.31,
        "open": 43.05
      },
      {
        "date": "3-Apr-12",
        "close": 629.32,
        "open": 46.03
      },
      {
        "date": "2-Apr-12",
        "close": 618.63,
        "open": 51.03
      },
      {
        "date": "30-Mar-12",
        "close": 599.55,
        "open": 53.42
      },
      {
        "date": "29-Mar-12",
        "close": 609.86,
        "open": 57.82
      },
      {
        "date": "28-Mar-12",
        "close": 617.62,
        "open": 59.01
      },
      {
        "date": "27-Mar-12",
        "close": 614.48,
        "open": 56.03
      },
      {
        "date": "26-Mar-12",
        "close": 606.98,
        "open": 50.01
      }
    ]
    
     // format the data
      data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.date = parseTime(d.date);
          d.close = +d.close;
          d.open = +d.open;
      });
    
      // Scale the range of the data
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
      y0.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return Math.max(d.close);})]);
      y1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return Math.max(d.open); })]);
    
      // Add the valueline path.
      svg.append("path")
          .data([data])
          .attr("class", "line")
          .style("fill", "#2a98cd")
          .style("fill-opacity", "0.3")
          .attr("d", valueline);
    
      // Add the valueline2 path.
      svg.append("path")
          .data([data])
          .attr("class", "line")
          .style("stroke", "red")
           .style("fill", "#df7247")
          .style("fill-opacity", "0.3")  
          .attr("d", valueline2);
    
      // Add the X Axis
      svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    
      // Add the Y0 Axis
      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axisSteelBlue")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y0));
    
      // Add the Y1 Axis
      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axisRed")
          .attr("transform", "translate( " + width + ", 0 )")
          .call(d3.axisRight(y1));      
    </script>
    </body>
```

I want this type of tooltip in this chart
[link]: http://bl.ocks.org/ChandrakantThakkarDigiCorp/1172532a84586f9659c193e1f5b16eb9

I want to show a tooltip while hovering it will show data of two lines for the current date like in the link it has shown.